# Data validation/constraint in Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a (likely) simple question about data validation in a Postgres DB.

I have the following table:

```
    Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id_number    | integer               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 last_name    | character varying(50) |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 first_name   | character varying(50) |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 school       | character varying(50) |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 district     | character varying(50) |           | not null |         | extended |              |
```

Code to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE students (
id_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
school VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
district VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
```

I want to create a list of valid input strings (text) for a column and reject any other input.

For example: for the "districts" column, I want the only input allowed to be "district a," district b," or "district c."

I've read over the [constraints documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html) but don't see anything about text constraints or using "or."

Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right at the top of the [linked documentation it discusses CHECK constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS), that's what you want here:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    ...
    district VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CHECK (district in ('district a', 'district b', 'district c')
);
```

Alternatively, you could add a separate table with the districts and then use a FOREIGN KEY constraint to restrict the districts to only those in the `districts` table.

For this you'd have something like:

```
create table districts (
    id integer not null primary key,
    name varchar not null
)
```

and then:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    id_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    school VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    district_id integer not null references districts(id)
)
```

and you'd JOIN to the `districts` table to get the district names.
Using a separate table would make it easier to get a list a possible districts, add new ones, remove old ones, and change the district's names. This would also be a more normalized approach, might be a little more work at the beginning but it is a big win later on.

Comment: I apologize for not responding via comment until now. Your solution worked great. Thank you.